# Newest fun riddle

Tags: riddle

I am one higher then pent up,
and a curse on your enemies.
The last civilization used me well,
and, out loud, a core of mathematics.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are:

> Hex

I am one higher than pent up

> The next highest numerical prefix after "pent-" is "hex-".

and a curse on your enemies

> "Hex" is a term for a curse.

The last civilization used me well

> Civilization V used hexagonal tiles with some success according to critics. (Thanks to Dan Russell on that one.)

and, out loud, a core of mathematics

> When spoken, some dialects pronounce "hex" and "x" very similar. $x$ is an incredibly common variable name in algebra.

Comment: I'd have imagined "hex" to be "hexadecimal" for the mathematics one, not necessary "x".

Comment: Hexadecimal is not particularly core to mathematics, though. If the puzzle were speaking more specifically about computer science, I would agree. Also, if it were talking about hexadecimal, it probably wouldn't include the "out loud" note.

Comment: Good point. Hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: Must resist urge to weigh the pros cons of civ5

Answer (score 10):

Are you:

> Hex

I am one higher than pent up

> Pent + 1 = Hex

and a curse on your enemies

> A hex on all y'all!

The last civilization used me well

> Civ V the game went to hexagonal tiles

and, out loud, a core of mathematics

> Hexadecimal encoding

Comment: I'd give you points also, but @Ian Macdonald has the most complete answer. Good work, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> hex

I am one higher then pent up,

> pent a prefix for five, hex a prefix for six

and a curse on your enemies.

> hex is synonymous with curse

The last civilization used me well,

> Referring to Greece?

and, out loud, a core of mathematics.

> hexadecimal

Comment: I had similar thoughts (nice match to your name, btw). However, I think that the last civilization used sextants (which is ... similar?).

Comment: I'd give you points also, but @Ian Macdonald has the most complete answer. Good work, though.